# Multiple ContainerRequestFilter for Jersey

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

We are planning on using Jersey's reference implementation for our REST APIs.  As a prototype effort, I was also playing around with the ContainerRequestFilters and I implemented multiple of them. Is there a way in which we can control the order in which these filters are executed?

The scenario that I am thinking over here is to ensure that the security filter must be the first one to run, and if required establish the SecurityContext and then execute other filters.

Comment: Which version of Jersey are you using?

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can control this with the `javax.annotation.Priority` attribute and the default `javax.ws.rs.Priorities`. For example if you wanted:

1. Logging filter always runs first
2. Authentication filter should run next
3. Authorization filter should run next
4. Custom filter should always run after others

You could do:

```
@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class CustomLoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        // DO LOGGING HERE, THIS RUNS FIRST
    }
}

@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        String authHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE);

        // DO AUTHENTICATION HERE, THIS RUNS SECOND
    }
}

@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        String authHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        // DO AUTHORIZATION HERE, THIS RUNS THIRD
    }
}

@Priority(Priorities.USER)
public class MyAwesomeStuffFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        // DO AWESOME STUFF HERE, THIS RUNS LAST
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using one library, that has one filter. 
And I have one of my own in application. Now I cannot add `@Priority` for library filter class. So that is running with default priority. How can I set the right precedence here so that my application filter runs before library's one?

Comment: @KiranAB : simply set a priority, on your filter, lower than the one one the library filter.